# Attempting to Change Description of a bunch of AD users with Powershell

Tags: powershell

I created a .csv file with Two rows.
Headers are "SamAccountName and NewDescription"

Does anyone know how to get a powershell to put the new description for each of the users listed?

I tried this code and it gives me an error with identity.

$Users = Import-Csv "C:\MyScripts\Service-Accounts 1.csv" foreach($User in $Users){Set-ADUser $User.SamAccountName -Description $User.NewDescription}

Comment: what error do you get? the code looks fine... but you may add the parameter -Identity in front of $User.SamAccountName

Comment: It was an -Identity null error but I just retyped it  and it worked.  Thanks anyway.

Comment: ....probably a record in the csv has this value not defined

Comment: Try using subexpressions :
`{Set-ADUser $($User.SamAccountName) -Description $($User.NewDescription)}`